# Loki Wifi keep turning off on ASUS X45U Laptop

Tags: release-loki, wifi

**My wifi keep turning off after 5 seconds**

First time first, i cant activate nor deactivate the wifi by Fn + F2 (Asus laptop problem, same old with Freya) usually i did connecting wifi by sleeping and unsleep the laptop, and voila the wifi connected.

I did the `sudo rfkill unblock all && rfkill list all` So here is my rfkill list all result

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

this is my lshw -C network result

```
  *-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 00
   serial: 08:3e:8e:3f:5d:a2
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-36-generic firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:16 memory:fea00000-fea0ffff


 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: 08:60:6e:98:2a:63
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:32 memory:fe900000-fe93ffff ioport:e000(size=128)


 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: enp0s16f0u2
   serial: 82:1d:5c:dd:6f:bb
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.145 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be affected by a bug described [here.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558) There is a workaround, but it doesn't fix the fn+f2 issue. See the link for full details, but here is a quick run down of what you should do.

run:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
```

This will show if you have a kernel driver in use and what it is called. You're looking for something like Kernel driver in use:ath9k.

Now run

```
lsmod | grep -e ath9k -e asus
```

Replace ath9k with your driver's name. This should show that the driver is loaded and show if asus_nb_wmi driver is being used. Assuming that asus_nd_wmi is being used run the following command and reboot.

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

Every boot will force asus_nb_wmi to use wapf=4, which is reported to fix the hardblock issue you have.

Comment: Thank you dude!, but i got another issue, why my WiFi signal strength so low, even if i got my router beside me..